# When to use Insert Select with Not Exist?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Currently I am inserting new data using Where as shown in the code below.  The obvious issue is the need to change the date on a daily basis for new data to be inserted.  Below is the current code being used:

```
INSERT INTO decisions (stock_id, date_price, last_updated_date, p_LT_d50, p_GT_d50)
SELECT stock_id, date_price, now(), adj_close_price < ub1_50_d, adj_close_price > ub1_50_d
FROM bollinger_bands
WHERE date_price = '8/04/2020';
```

Instead of manually changing the date on a daily basis, can I use Where Not Exist?  Should I be using Where Not Exist to solve the problem I am having?  If so, what do I fill in for the Where Not Exist portion of Select?

This is what I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO decisions (stock_id, date_price, last_updated_date, p_LT_d50, p_GT_d50)
SELECT stock_id, date_price, now(), adj_close_price < ub1_50_d, adj_close_price > ub1_50_d
FROM bollinger_bands
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to bypass the need to change the daily date when there are new data entered into the bollinger band table.  New data is entered into the bollinger band table on a daily basis, so I would like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: You want to replace '8/04/2020' with the current date? `WHERE date_price = current_date`?

Comment: that's what I guessed but I really don't understand why one would think EXISTS has anything to do with it

Comment: That is why I asked the question " Should I be using Where Not Exist to solve the problem I am having?"  I am new to coding, so I am not sure what to use.

Comment: The problem with using current_date is the data is stock price data.  New stock price data is generated after each daily close, which is 4pm EST.  Sometimes I don't run other scripts needed to generate the data until the next morning.  I am not sure using current_date would not capture the data for the previous day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT stock_id, date_price, now(), adj_close_price < ub1_50_d, adj_close_price > ub1_50_d
FROM bollinger_bands bb
WHERE bb.date_price > (SELECT max(d.date_price) FROM decisions d)
```

Comment: Thank you.  The code did exactly what I needed it to do.  One part I don't really understand is the bb2 portion of code.  Why is it used instead of decisions?

Comment: @UnderlyingExposure . . . Because I mistyped the table name.

Answer (score 3):

Insert the current day's data:

```
INSERT INTO decisions (stock_id, date_price, last_updated_date, p_LT_d50, p_GT_d50)
SELECT stock_id, date_price, now(), adj_close_price < ub1_50_d, adj_close_price > ub1_50_d
FROM bollinger_bands
WHERE date_price = CURRENT_DATE;
```

Insert all dates still missing from the table:

```
INSERT INTO decisions (stock_id, date_price, last_updated_date, p_LT_d50, p_GT_d50)
SELECT stock_id, date_price, now(), adj_close_price < ub1_50_d, adj_close_price > ub1_50_d
FROM bollinger_bands
WHERE date_price NOT IN (SELECT date_price FROM decisions);
```

The same with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO decisions (stock_id, date_price, last_updated_date, p_LT_d50, p_GT_d50)
SELECT stock_id, date_price, now(), adj_close_price < ub1_50_d, adj_close_price > ub1_50_d
FROM bollinger_bands bb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM decisions d WHERE d.date_price = bb.date_price);
```

Comment: I am trying to learn and your examples are very helpful for future purposes.  Thank you.